# PYQT 4: How can i call a GUI Function in another class?

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, pyqt4

I will make 2 examples to explain it

I created a Button that when i click it, it shows a message in the TextEdit Widget (in this case it shows "A string").

If i do that in the same class of the GUI, i have no problems:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class Aplicacion(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Aplicacion, self).__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit('')
        self.button = QPushButton("Do anything")

        #Layouts
        vbox.addWidget(self.textedit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)


        #Connections
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.aFunction)

    def aFunction(self):
        self.textedit.append("A string")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = Aplicacion()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

It works fine: http://puu.sh/kpEHC.png

But when i am trying to do the same in another class or function i get this error:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

def appendAnything(self):
    Aplicacion().textedit.append("test")  # HERE IS THE ERROR




class Aplicacion(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Aplicacion, self).__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit('')
        self.button = QPushButton("Do anything")

        #Layouts
        vbox.addWidget(self.textedit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)


        #Connections
        self.button.clicked.connect(appendAnything)

    def aFunction(self):
        self.textedit.append("A string")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = Aplicacion()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

Error:

```
Aplicacion().textedit.append("test")  # HERE IS THE ERROR
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTextEdit has been deleted
```

Image: http://puu.sh/kpETO.png

Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are creating a new `Aplicacion` instances inside the function scope and it gets destroyed as soon as your code goes back to the main loop since you don't keep any reference of this new instance. Also I don't understand why you are creating a new `Aplicacion` instance: I think you should probably pass a reference of your main widget to the function. An easy (non thread safe) way to do that is to use `partial`:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from functools import partial 
import sys

def appendAnything(self, app):
    app.textedit.append("test")

class Aplicacion(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Aplicacion, self).__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit('')
        self.button = QPushButton("Do anything")

        #Layouts
        vbox.addWidget(self.textedit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        #Connections
        self.button.clicked.connect(partial(appendAnything, app=self))

    def aFunction(self):
        self.textedit.append("A string")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Aplicacion()
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```